# Dovecot IMAPS . Port 993 , telnet NO IMAP handshake message but telnet port 143 does

Tags: postfix-mta, dovecot

I am trying to setup a postfix/dovecot on ubuntu 20.x

After DOVECOT configuration I can connect(thru telnet, from my iPhone using gmail client) to port 143 and get IMAP handshake message, login etc.
BUT I get authentication failed error when connecting to port 993 (from iPhone)

then

I tried telnet 'mymailserver' 993 and get no IMAP handshake message..

Moreover, when i do openssl s_client -connect 'mailserver' 993 , I get the handshake message as expected..

Can someone help ?

Here is my dovecot -n

```
root@mail:/usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d# dovecot -n
# 2.3.7.2 (3c910f64b): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.7.2 ()
# OS: Linux 5.4.0-131-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
# Hostname: ****************

auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_username_format = %n
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = " imap lmtp pop3"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 110
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 995
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service submission-login {
  inet_listener submission {
    port = 587
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/..../fullchain.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

Comment: 993 means IMAP over SSL/TLS. If you connect to that via Telnet you *should not* get an IMAP handshake message, but instead be able to initiate a TLS connection. In other words: the behaviour you describe sounds exactly like it should be. Why do you want a different behaviour?

Comment: @JoachimSauer, exactly...then why am i not not getting the IMAP handshake message when i do telnet 'myserver-FQDN' 993  but when I use openssl s_client -connect.... i get he message as expected...why ?

Comment: Because 993 isn't for talking IMAP over a plain tcp/ip connect (i.e. what the telnet client expects). You **first** must make a successful TLS connection and then you'll get an IMAP handshake **over that TLS connection**. Just like you can't just send `GET / HTTP/1.0` to port 443 of a web server and expect to get a sane answer. That's the very nature of TLS.

Comment: @JoachimSauer ok. agreed..and thank you for reinstating my confidence in the setup...BTW by magic..suddenly iPhone seems to go thru the setup with port 993..but need to investigate this further..I am on a VPS from GoDaddy..Thak you!